# Existe diferença em se usar atributos HTML5 com ou sem true/false?

Tags: html, html5

Existe a possibilidade de ocorrer algum tipo de problema no código quando não atribuo um valor booleano aos atributos `disabled`, `readonly` ou `required`?

Estou trabalhando com Java no back-end e a IDE aponta erro de html quando atribuo um valor booleano ao atributo,  talvez por causa do XML, não sei. Há algum tipo de problema deixar sem o *boolean*? Existe uma regra para se colocar `true` ou `false` nestes atributos HTML?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nmPessoa" required>      // aceito

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nmPessoa" required="true"> //msg
```

> **MSG**: Undefined attribute value (true).

Comment: Por curiosidade, onde viu esta mensagem?

Comment: Não é bem um erro, seria mais como uma mensagem de alerta, fica com sinal de exclamação dentro de um triângulo amarelo ao lado da numeração da linhas.

Comment: Mas aonde fica esse sinal de exclamação? No console, no validador no w3.org?

Comment: Ao lado da numeração das linhas da própria IDE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tais atributos são chamados de [atributos booleanos](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#boolean-attributes) - e, não oficialmente, em alguns lugares, de propriedade.

Como previsto na especificação, apenas a presença do atributo já é suficiente para considerar como verdadeiro, assim como sua ausência como falso. Além disso, para manter retro-compatibilidade, manteve-se também o padrão de o atributo poder receber uma *string* não vazia com o mesmo nome do atributo.

Portanto, `required` e `required="required"` são atributos válidos.

Na própria especificação diz:

> *The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.*

Isto é, valores como `"true"` e `"false"` não são permitidos em atributos booleanos (em outros, sim). Para definir como falso, basta omitir o atributo do elemento.

Assim,

```
<input type="checkbox" checked name="cheese" disabled>
```

É equivalente a

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="cheese" disabled="disabled">
```

Inclusive podendo misturar os padrões e omitir as aspas:

```
<input type=checkbox checked=checked name=cheese disabled>
```

Veja funcionando:

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked name="cheese" disabled> Sem valores
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="cheese" disabled="disabled"> Com valores
<input type=checkbox checked=checked name=cheese disabled> Misturado
```

Mesmo sendo previsto, a especificação acaba sendo apenas uma **sugestão** de padronização, o que não significa que todos os navegadores irão implementá-la fielmente. Acredito que todos os principais navegadores atuais irão considerar `"true"` como verdadeiro, mas isso pode alterar sem aviso prévio em qualquer versão, em qualquer navegador. Não há motivos para se usar.

Answer (score 10):

Você pode usar ferramentas online para verificar isso. A própria W3C tem um validador online de HTML e CSS

- https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options

Repare que quando você usa o atributo e coloca o valor booleano `True` ou `False` a ferramenta dá o alerta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui tem a documentação oficial W3C sobre os atributos do `input` no HTML 5

- https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#sec-states-of-the-type-attribute

> 2.4.2. Boolean attributes
>
> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a boolean attribute on an element
>   represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents
>   the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string
>   or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute’s
>   canonical name, with no leading or trailing white space.

Em suma, esses são atributos que não precisam de `True` ou `False`, pois quando está ausentes são `False` por *default*, mas se estão presentes no `input` são consideradas `True` por *default*. Na verdade os argumentos `True` e `False` são ignorados pelo *browser*, pois não são valores aceitos para esse tipo de atributo, por isso apresentam o erro na validação.

*Fonte:* https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#sec-boolean-attributes

Comment: Legal este validador, não conhecia!

Comment: @LeAndrade repare que ele tem vária opções de validação, inclusive vc pode copiar e colar seu documento inteiro ali, desde que ele seja apenas HTML, se tiver js etc vai apresentar inúmeros erros. a W3C tb tem uma ferramenta para validar o CSS vale a pena olhar

Comment: Top mesmo, muito legal.

Answer (score 6):

O primeiro é correto, o segundo pode funcionar por coincidência em alguns navegadores. Uma *string* é considerada um valor válido, portanto verdadeiro, então só por acaso funciona.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nmPessoa" required="false">
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/Required.html).

Isto continua sendo requerido? Sim, continua, não importa o que está escrito nela, uma *string* com um conteúdo significa verdadeiro, mas passa a ideia errada de que não é requerido.

Pelo menos a [especificação do HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-required-attribute) (o que está usando, de acordo com a pergunta) diz que o atributo não tem valores. Os navegadores costumam fazer o melhor esforço de interpretação e acabam aceitando um valor, mesmo não importando o que ele seja, o valor será ignorado. EM código 100% válido não deve colocar nada.

Comment: Maniero parece que true e false na verdade não são atributos validos, então o esforço do browser seria para simplesmente desconcidera-los como argumento. Então apesar de poder funcionar o HTML não vai ser validado como vc pode testar nesse link de validação da própria W3C https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options

Comment: Que foi o que eu escrevi, só usei uma palavra errado, corrigida agora.

Answer (score 2):

Problema não há, o `HTML` vai identificar e aplicar a propriedade independentemente se é `true` ou `false`.

já na documentação dos atributos há uma menção sobre esse tipo de atributo no `XHTML`, ou sejá se tratando de `XHTML` é necessário o uso do `required="required"`, isso também para `disabled` e `readonly`

Se tratando de HTML 4.01 e HTML5 o atributo pode ficar sozinho...

Comment: Uma correção: não é o HTML que irá identificar isso, mas sim os navegadores. Uma vez que esse comportamento não é documentado, ele pode ser alterado a qualquer momento.