# Ajuda para bloquear um campo do form

Tags: php, formulário

tenho um formulário onde se coloca pedidos de compra qdo o usuário escolhe o produto ele traz o preço automaticamente, o problema é que o campo de valor unitário fica livre para alterações e preciso bloquear esse campo.

Tentei o normal que é readonly="readonly" mas ele continua permitindo alterações.

Tentei com o disabled esse desabilita o campo para alterações mas também não grava esse valor no bd

Qual outro meio de bloquear o campo e gravar no bd esse valore recebido na seleção do produto?

PS: tenho outros campos nesse formulário que uso readonly="readonly" que funciona perfeitamente como por exemplo o resultado da multiplicação da qtd pelo preço unitário o campo total do item o usuário não consegue alterar

o formulário está assim:

```
<td> 
<input name="valor_unid[]" type="text" required name="valor_unid"  
maxlength="30" size="11" style="text-align:center" class="valor_unid" />
</td>
```

Comment: Tentou usar por javascript assim
document.getElementById("myText").readOnly = true;

Comment: Já tentou colocar "disable"? (sem as aspas).

Comment: Acredito que esteja dando algum erro por vc estar usando readonly="readonly", tente colocar apenas `readonly` Essa reposta tem umas coisas que podem te interessar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/313349/existe-diferen%C3%A7a-em-se-usar-atributos-html5-com-ou-sem-true-false/

Comment: Leandro já usei disable sem aspas e mesmo assim ele não grava no BD Hugocsl já tentei também só readonly e mesmo assim deixa alterar

Comment: Se puder tirar o input, coloca o valor dentro de um `<p></p>`

Comment: Sem o imput o valor não vai aparecer na tela

Comment: Coloca type="hidden" no input e coloca o valor fora do campo também.

Comment: dvd....valeu não tinha pensado nessa possibilidade...funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque `type="hidden"` no `input` com o valor e fora dele também. Assim o valor ficará visível para o usuário no `<td>` e o `input` oculto também guardará o mesmo valor:

```
<td>
    <?php echo $valor ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $valor ?>" name="valor_unid[]" type="text" required name="valor_unid" maxlength="30" size="11" style="text-align:center" class="valor_unid" />
</td>
```